# HTML Beautify like tool for PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

In sublime text I use a plugin called HTML Beautify to clean up html indenting that I have messed up, etc.

Is there a good plugin or method for doing this same task in PyCharm?

Comment: It's there by default, you don't need a plugin. Tap `Shift` twice and type `reformat`. You should see something like `Reformat Code` with a key binding. Now press `Enter` to reformat your code. Try using the key binding for quicker formatting next time.

Comment: I dont know sometime pycharm is buggy it will not format it even after reformat code clicked

Answer (score 8):

Press Ctrl+Shift+Alt+L for code reformatting.

[see this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/reformatting-source-code.html)

Comment: For mac: ⌘Cmd + ⌥Option + Shift + L

Comment: I recapped it to f3 but yep that's the winner!